# Python regex ignore new line

Tags: php, python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I have web page look like this

```
<td valign="top">

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" class="main_tb3">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div align="center">
                <a href="/title/name.php" target="_blank">
                <img src="./movie/image.jpg" alt="TitleName" border="0" height="100" width="225" />
                </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><h1 align="center"><a href="./title.php?titleid=12">Title - secondname</a></h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="style10">Cat1 :</span></td>
            <td>1st name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="32%"><span class="style10">Cat2 :</span></td>
            <td width="68%"><b><i><a href="./secondname.php" target="_blank">secondname</a></i></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="style10">cat4 :</span></td>
            <td>Bla bla</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="style10">Cat3 :</span></td>
            <td>thirdName2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</td>
<td valign="top">

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" class="main_tb3">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div align="center">
                <a href="/title/name.php" target="_blank">
                <img src="./movie/image.jpg" alt="TitleName" border="0" height="100" width="225" />
                </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><h1 align="center"><a href="./title.php?titleid=12">Title - secondname</a></h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="style10">Cat1 :</span></td>
            <td>1st name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="32%"><span class="style10">Cat2 :</span></td>
            <td width="68%"><b><i><a href="./secondname.php" target="_blank">secondname</a></i></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="style10">cat4 :</span></td>
            <td>Bla bla</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="style10">Cat3 :</span></td>
            <td>thirdName2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</td>
```

I would like to get certain values from this site using python regex.
After `<div align="center">` I like to get href value: "/title/name.php" and img src: "./movie/image.jpg" and Title - secondname from `<h1 align="center"><a href="./title.php?titleid=12">Title - secondname</a></h1>`

i have tried this:
`regex   = 'class="main_tb3"*\n<a href="(.+?)" target="_blank">\n<img src="(.+?)"'`

please help me

Comment: I'll just drop this here: http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/ => _You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML._

Comment: use [`beautifulsoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below regex

> For href value: `<a href="(.*?)"`
>
> For Image src: `<img src="(.*?)"`
>
> For Title: `titleid=12">(.*?)<`

Answer (score 0):

You will find it a lot simpler to install something like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<td valign="top">

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" class="main_tb3">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div align="center">
                <a href="/title/name.php" target="_blank">
                <img src="./movie/image.jpg" alt="TitleName" border="0" height="100" width="225" />
                </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><h1 align="center"><a href="./title.php?titleid=12">Title - secondname</a></h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="style10">Cat1 :</span></td>
            <td>1st name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="32%"><span class="style10">Cat2 :</span></td>
            <td width="68%"><b><i><a href="./secondname.php" target="_blank">secondname</a></i></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="style10">cat4 :</span></td>
            <td>Bla bla</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="style10">Cat3 :</span></td>
            <td>thirdName2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</td>
<td valign="top">

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" class="main_tb3">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div align="center">
                <a href="/title/name.php" target="_blank">
                <img src="./movie/image.jpg" alt="TitleName" border="0" height="100" width="225" />
                </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><h1 align="center"><a href="./title.php?titleid=12">Title - secondname</a></h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="style10">Cat1 :</span></td>
            <td>1st name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="32%"><span class="style10">Cat2 :</span></td>
            <td width="68%"><b><i><a href="./secondname.php" target="_blank">secondname</a></i></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="style10">cat4 :</span></td>
            <td>Bla bla</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="style10">Cat3 :</span></td>
            <td>thirdName2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for table in soup.find_all("table", class_="main_tb3"):
    print table.find('a').get('href')
    print table.find('h1').text
```

For the HTML you have given, this will print the following:

```
/title/name.php
Title - secondname
/title/name.php
Title - secondname
```